# Триггер для накопления данных в поле

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Используется**
MySql 5,7 - х64

Имеется таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `tst_005_tbl_00` (
    `id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pl_1` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pl_1_sprch` ENUM('pl_1_1','pl_1_2','pl_1_3','pl_1_4','pl_1_5','pl_1_6') NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Сценарий**
1. В поле **"pl_1_sprch"** выбираем значение из выпадающего списка;
2. В поле **"pl_1"** триггер добавляет новые значение к существующим значениям через запятую.

**Вопрос**
1. Можно ли реализовать данный сценарий?
2. Если "да", то как ориентировочно должно выглядеть решение?
3. Какими другими способами можно решить данную задачу?
4. Как сделать, чтобы данные в поле, где собираются метки не повторялись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно (хотя под вопросом из за enum), но не нужно. Работать с данными через запятую в реляционных БД крайне не удобно. Данные хранящиеся в таком виде вызывают массу проблем. В реляционных БД в таких случаях создают отдельную таблицу в которой лежит id записи из основной таблицы и отдельное значение из списка и так несколько строк. После такой [*нормализации*](http://i-novice.net/6-normalnyx-form-bd/) все сразу встает на свои места, enum начинает работать как ему предписано - хранить одно значение из нескольких.

Практически во всех случаях, когда необходимо хранить множественные значения, реализация работы с такой таблицей на клиенте достаточно проста. Это может быть список с галочками, на все выбранные пункты просто даем insert. Или, например, теги к статьям (как на stackoverflow), там человек явно добавляет по очереди значения (или удаляет их) нам требуется его действия превратить в insert или delete.

Кстати, если список возможных значений расширяемый, т.е. может расти в будущем, то вместо enum лучше воспользоваться отдельной таблицей - справочником возможных значений. Тогда полная структура будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
Таблица теги:
ID-тега
Название

Ваша таблица tst_005_tbl_00
ID
другие поля

Связующая таблица "Теги статьи"
ID-tbl_00
ID-тега
primary key (ID-tbl_00, ID-тега),
foreign key ID-tbl_00 references tst_005_tbl_00(ID),
foreign key ID-тега references Теги(ID-тега)
```

Comment: Пока сделал как понимаю: - справочник меток; - таблица Статей (статьям будут присваиваться метки); таблица журнал меток для статей; триггер_обновления(при обновлении метки в журнал заносится id статьи и метка.)1. Правильно ли я понял ваше предложение ? См. код https://codeshare.io/GApzdw. 2. Как сделать, чтобы триггер осуществлял проверку метки на уникальность? Т.е. если в журнале для статьи метка уже есть, то она не заносится в журнал... Или просто поялвяется сообщение об ошибке

Comment: @koverflow Что то я вообще не понял, зачем вам триггер, зачем вы метку заносите  из приложения в поле таблицы статей. Как вы собираетесь вносить несколько меток ? по хорошему ваше приложение не должно давать update на статьи а сразу писать в таблицу связи меток со статьями. И ваши таблицы какие то странные. В неком справочнике меток нет уникального ключа и вообще нет ID. А id метки появляется в некоем журнале, где метки связаны со статьями и следовательно не могут быть уникальны